# How to correctly handle concurrent access to the same variable?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

In my system I want to create pretty similar functionality to bank accounts. I have got some kind of balances that we can operate on. Let's illustrate it by an example.

I have got two tables for balances and operations on it:

```
Balances
(
   Id int,
   Balance decimal
)

Operations
(
    Id int,
    FK_BalancesId int,
    Value decimal
)
```

When I want to add 500 to the particular balance I just save an operation with BalanceId and the Value I want to add. Likewise I want to substract 500 I just save operation with Value "-500". Of course before I save substract operation I have to check if the balance added to all the operations made on the balance are above the substract value.

My problem is when 2 people in pretty similar time wants to subtract "-500". 
When someone wants to add operation "-500", I just get all operations on particular balance, sum them up with the balance and check if this sum is bigger or equal 500. (I don't want to get negative numbers on balance). But what about situation when 2 people want to do such an operation at pretty similar time? Here is the scenario I dont know how to handle:

```
A wants add operation "-500"
B wants add operation "-500"
System check for A - balance is 750 operation is allowed
System check for B - balance is 750 operation is allowed
A save operation "-500"
B save operation "-500"
```

And after that balance is below 0 (-250). How to correctly and clean handle such a situations?

Comment: You've tagged this `sql-server`, but your question's about a "variable". It's not clear what parts of your system are going to the database, and what parts are doing things in memory. For a pure database approach, the obvious solution is a transaction with locking -- as A checks the balance, locks are taken out on the `Balances` row, and B has to wait until A's entire transaction completes, after which B checks the (now updated) balance.

Comment: `lock` it or `revert` it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, my app is written in C# (WCF) where I use Dapper to connect to the Database with the repository pattern. I can make it on the backend side in C# & Dapper, or just invoke stored procedures etc. with Dapper, so there is no any part of the system im bound to. I am just looking for the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the whole thing should be done in SQL Server, and that these are the real table definitions below - I changed "Id" in the Operations table to be an identity column. The following procedure will check the balance to be sure that the transaction will not create a negative balance, update the balance with the amount given, and return the value of the Operations Id that was inserted.  If the balance would go negative then NULL will be returned as the Operations Id, and the balance left alone.  The procedure allows you to pass the operation as a string since you placed quotes around the value in your question and examples.

```
CREATE TABLE Balances
(
   Id INT,
   Balance DECIMAL
)

CREATE TABLE Operations
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    FK_BalancesId INT,
    Value DECIMAL
)
GO 

--insert the beginning balance 
insert into Balances values (1, 750)
GO 


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SaveOperation
    @BalanceId INT
    , @OperationAmount VARCHAR(100)
AS

DECLARE @OperationsId INT
DECLARE @Balance DECIMAL
DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL

SET @Amount = CAST(@OperationAmount AS DECIMAL)

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    SET @Balance = (SELECT B.Balance FROM Balances WITH (SERIALIZABLE) WHERE Id = @BalanceId)

    -- [+] operation assuming amount will be a negative number
    IF (@Balance + @Amount > 0)
        BEGIN

        UPDATE Balances SET Balance = Balance + @Amount

        INSERT INTO Operations (FK_BalancesId, Value) VALUES (@BalanceId, @Amount)

        SET @OperationsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        END

COMMIT TRANSACTION 

SELECT @OperationsId
```

Usage:

```
exec sp_SaveOperation 1, '-500';
_________________________________
Returns 1

exec sp_SaveOperation 1, '-500';
_________________________________
Returns NULL


select * from balances;
____________________________
Id    Balance
1     250

select * from operations;
____________________________
Id    FK_BalancesId    Value
1     1                -500
```

Comment: This only works under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, or with an explicit table hint to that effect in the `SELECT .. FROM Balances`. Otherwise, the transaction can still pass the `IF` and execute the update, since the default `READ COMMITTED` level will not cause the `SELECT` to lock the row.

Comment: What is the Table hint?  I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Either `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` or `FROM Balances WITH (SERIALIZABLE)` would do. (Some people may prefer `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`, which is the same thing, but emphasizes a lock is held.)

Comment: added FROM Balances WITH (SERIALIZABLE)   Your comment gives them other options as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I believe you didn't fully understand my post, maybe i didn't write it clear enough. The main difference i expect is that i dont want to manipulate the Balance table. All operations will be saved in the Operations table. When I want to check the balance i get the value from Balance table and add all the values from operations table to this.

Comment: Got it.  Seems like you are going to do a ton of processing each time you want to check for the updated balance.  In that case just get the sum of the operations and compare them against the opening balance.